# Comparing QString to 0. Is it valid?

Tags: qt4

What happens, in this code:

```
QString s;
if(s!=0)
```

which operator or cast will be applied here? 
Is it valid? (it does compile)
Is it similar to isNull or isEmpty?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it use `bool QString::​operator==(const char * other) const` 
operator (or in your case !=) to compare your string with `const char *`. So `QString()` would be equal to 0. This allows you to compare `QString("Hello")` with `"Hello"`.

This can be disabled with

```
DEFINES += QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII
```

in your project file. Make sure that you `clean` and `rebuild` your app after you add this change to project file.